# How do you Configure Stapi CMS to Use Custom Domain Name

Tags: deployment, content-management-system, hostname, strapi

The default port for [strapi](https://strapi.io/) is `1337`, and default hostname is "Localhost".

I changed the hostname in the server.json file (that's inside the development folder) to "example.com" and saved that change.

However, when I start the program (by typing `npm start` in the terminal) although the output indicates that strapi is indeed hosting on "example.org" (and says the administration is at "example.org/admin"), upon navigating to `example.org:1337`, in a web browser, the page is not accessible. Yet, it **is** accessible when I navigate to `localhost:1337`.

I'm new to strapi. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello! Where did you host your application?

Comment: hi jim , i hosted on  AWS EC2

Answer (score 0):

Changing the domain name, inside of a server.json configuration file, won't likely result in your web browser being able to resolve that domain.

When your web browser tries to discover the IP address of a domain name, it first looks in your operating system's [host file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)). If it cannot find the ip address of the domain there, it then tries to look for it at the [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) server that provides name-lookup for your local network.

DNS will typically point your domain to the public IP address of your web server and sometimes, if your web server is located on the same [LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network) you are, it can be tricky to teach the firewall or local DNS server how to route your browser's request within your LAN.

If you do edit your host file, to make the domain point to an internal IP address, you'll want to remove that entry later in order to access the domain when you are not on your LAN.

Comment: hi Lonnie , but i can't change the host file of each user locally or force them to. i am deploying this on AWS EC2 and want to available to the users. thanks for the response.